# Type mismatches in Haskell `do` with multiple return values

Tags: haskell, type-mismatch, do-notation

I have the following code, but on compile I am getting several errors. Can I return two variables as a tuple from a `do` statement?

```
Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘(,) String’
      Expected type: (String, Char)
        Actual type: String
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: f <- string_prog (g)

Couldn't match expected type ‘(String, t0)’
                  with actual type ‘Int’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: tx <- mult_prog x y

Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 -> Int’ with actual type ‘Char’
    • The function ‘f’ is applied to one argument,
      but its type ‘Char’ has none
```

```
    mult_prog :: Int -> Int -> Int
    mult_prog one1 one2 = one1 * one2
                            
    string_prog :: String -> String
    string_prog s = ("  " ++ s ++ "   ")     
    
    
    do_prog :: String -> Int -> Int -> (String, Int)
    
    do_prog g x y =   do f <- string_prog(g)  
    
                         tx <- mult_prog x y
    
                         return $ f tx
```

Comment: please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<-` is for "extracting" values from monads, which your values aren't (not in the way you think they are at least). `return` is for wrapping a value in a monad, which your return value isn't. Instead, use `let` and just have a tuple as the final value:

```hs
mult_prog :: Int -> Int -> Int
mult_prog one1 one2 = one1 * one2
                        
string_prog :: String -> String
string_prog s = ("  " ++ s ++ "   ")     


do_prog :: String -> Int -> Int -> (String, Int)
do_prog g x y = do let f = string_prog g
                   let tx = mult_prog x y
                   (f, tx)
```

Note that you don't even need `do` and you can just use `let...in`:

```hs
mult_prog :: Int -> Int -> Int
mult_prog one1 one2 = one1 * one2
                        
string_prog :: String -> String
string_prog s = ("  " ++ s ++ "   ")     


do_prog :: String -> Int -> Int -> (String, Int)
do_prog g x y = let f = string_prog g
                    tx = mult_prog x y
                 in (f, tx)
```

Comment: the first snippet and the fact that it works at all and why, is better left to the curiosities department, not presented to newcomers to the language, which are bound to only get confused by it.

Comment: thanks for the clarification and the note on monads